# Double integral parallelogram

Tags: integration, limits, definite-integrals

I'm trying to solve the following problem:

> Calculate $$ \iint_D (5x+5y) dx dy$$ where $D$ is a parallelogram with vertices at the points $\{ (0,0) (-5,5) (5,4) (0,9) \}$.

I'm not sure how to start but one way might be to first find the equations for the lines between the points. Hoewever, I don't know how to move forward from there. What will the upper and lower limits of the integral be?

Comment: Please take a look at [this article](https://mathinsight.org/double_integral_examples). It will refresh your memory on how to solve double integrals. Specifically, refer to example 2.

Comment: I have four points now, that will give me different intervalls, but I still don't understand what the limits will be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compute the integral we divide the parallelogram into three regions $D_1, D_2, D_3$. $D_1$ is the region bounded by the vertices $(0,0)$, $(-5,5)$ and $(0,5)$. The bounds of the integral for this region are the lines $y = -x$, $y = 5$ and $x = 0$. We now compute the integral over $D_1$:

$$F_1 = \int_{-5}^0 \int_{-x}^5 5x+ 5y dxdy$$
$$= \int_{-5}^0 \left[ 5xy + \frac{5}{2} y^2 \right]_{-x}^5dx$$
$$= \int_{-5}^0 25x + \frac{125}{2} + \frac{5}{2}x^2dx$$
$$= \frac{625}{6}$$

We now consider the region $D_2$. $D_2$ is the region bounded by the lines $x = 0$, $x = 4$, $y = 0$ and $y = 5$. We compute the integral over the region $D_2$:

$$F_2 = \int_{0}^4 \int_{0}^5 5x+ 5y dxdy$$
$$= \int_{0}^4  \left[ 5xy + \frac{5}{2}y^2 \right]_0^5dx$$
$$= \int_{0}^4  25x + \frac{125}{2}dx$$
$$= 450$$

And now we consider the final region $D_3$. $D_3$ is the region bounded by the lines $x = 4$, $y = 0$ and $y = -x + 9$. The integral over the region $D_3$ is:

$$F_3 = \int_4^9 \int_0^{-x + 9} 5x + 5ydxdy$$
$$= \int_4^9 \left[ 5xy + \frac{5}{2}y^2 \right]_0^{-x + 9} dx$$
$$= \int_4^9 5x(-x + 9) + \frac{5}{2} (-x + 9)^2 dx$$
$$= \frac{1375}{3}$$

The final answer is then $F_1 + F_2 + F_3 = \frac{2025}{2}$.